# More than one sliding menu in a page

Tags: html, css, menu, slidingmenu

I've managed to make a sliding menu link, but when I try to make another it doesn't work like the first one.

Here's a wireframe of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Wireframe]

```css
/*HOME MENU*/

#home {
  position: fixed;
  left: -8.5em;
  top: 20px;
  width: 8em;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  margin: -1em 0 0 0;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 2.5em;
  transition: 0.2s
}

#home:hover {
  left: 0
}

#home a {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.2s
}

#home a:link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#home a:visited {
  color: green;
}

#home a:hover {
  color: gray;
}

#home a:active {
  left: -7em;
  background: hsla(80, 90%, 40%, 0.7);
  color: white;
}

#home a:focus {
  left: -7em;
  background: hsla(80, 90%, 40%, 0.7);
}

/*3D MENU*/

#3D {
  position: fixed;
  left: -8.5em;
  top: 20px;
  width: 8em;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  margin: -4em 0 0 0;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 2.5em;
  transition: 0.2s
}

#3D:hover {
  left: 0
}

#3D a {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.2s
}

#3D a:link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#3D a:visited {
  color: green;
}

#3D a:hover {
  color: gray;
}

#3D a:active {
  left: -7em;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

#3D a:focus {
  left: -7em;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<ul id="home">
  <a href="#home">PERFIL<img src="menu/home.png" style="max-width:32px; height:auto;" align="right"></a>
</ul>
<ul id="3D">
  <a href="#3D">GRAFICA 3D<img src="menu/3d.jpg" style="max-width:32px;height:auto;" align="right"></a>
</ul>
```

([*fiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/Ariel_Tapia/n25htuqb/9/))

Comment: Do you want the list items to be inline or block? Horizontally aligned or vertically?

Comment: I am asking because in the wireframe, they are aligned vertically. I see theres a beautiful reply already, using flexbox etc, that is solid.

Comment: Each of the sliding menus doesn't contain dropdowns, They are more of a sliding hyperlinked object to be honest.

Comment: I understand that, but do you want each link to be on top of the next or next to eachother?

Comment: I think next to eachother is good. The replied answer is what basically I was looking for. English isn't my native language, so I'm sorry if I didn't understand at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your semantic seems a little bit confusing. You should avoid inline-scripts and 'ul' tags without 'li' inside.
Your css strategy is nice, but you are repeating information, wich is bad for maintenance. I wrote your code into a better semantic and CSS.

To achieve your slider, i'm using CSS transform property.

```css
.wrapper * {
  overflow:hidden;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.wrapper ul li {
  display:flex;
  margin-bottom:4px;
}
.wrapper ul li a {
  background:black;
  color:white;
  padding:5px 10px;
  transform: translateX(calc(-100% + 32px));
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
  
}
.wrapper img {
  max-width:32px;
  margin-left:5px;
}
.wrapper ul li a:hover {
  background:black;
  color:white;
  padding:5px 10px;
  transform: translateX(0);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul id="home">
    <li id="item1">
      <a href="#home">TEST1<img src="menu/home1.png"></a>
    </li>
    
    <li id="item2">
      <a href="#home">TEST2<img src="menu/home2.png"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's the exact thing I was looking for. By the way, how can I make it so there's a bit more space from each other (like in the wareframe)?

Comment: If you change margin-bottom property you can change vertical space between them.